# React+Material UI: How to make a Box occupy all the remaining vertical space?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a web app using React + Material UI. I have three `Box` components (see the code that follows). `Box 1` and `Box 3` have fixed heights. How can I force `Box 2` to occupy the remaining vertical space?

```
<Box id="1" sx={{height: "90vh"}}>
    <Box id="2">
        
    </Box>
    <Box id="3" sx={{height: "50px"}}>
        
    </Box>
</Box>
```

Comment: `<Box id="2" style={{ flex: 1  }}>
</Box>`

Comment: ^ this but replace style with sx instead since that's what Box component expects

Comment: No, this didn't work! "Box 2" does not expand to take up all the remaining space. :-(

Comment: @JosédeFrança Did you ever figure this out? What did you do?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "100vh"
});
```